# Counting instances of each Month based on IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

Assume I have the following table setup:

```
    Date             Product Type        Supplier
   12-May-2015           C                XX
   23-Sep-2015           B                XK
   12-May 2015           C                XA
```

How can I count the number of times supplier `XX` shows up for product `C` in `May` by using no macros or VBA?

My logic would be something like:

```
IF Product Type = C and Supplier = XX THEN and Month = May, THEN count.
```

But I am stumped on what functions to use as I understand there is no looping function in Excel without macros. I can't even use COUNTIF because I need to check IF statements first.

Comment: Build a month column? Edit: btw, you want `countifs` with the s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

Type this into an empty cell:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(A2:A4)=5,1,0) * IF(B2:B4="C",1,0) * IF(C2:C4="XX",1,0))
```

After entering the formula, hold `CONTROL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` to indicate that it is an array formula.

Comment: Works perfect. Might I ask why making it an array took away my error which said that value was of the wrong data type (when using the exact formula you provided)?

Comment: I'm not sure... I can't reproduce the error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the dates that span the month in which you are interested into I1 (earlier) and J1 (later), the `Product` in K1 and `Suppplier` in L1 then (as @findwindow has suggested):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">"&I1,A:A,"<"&J1,B:B,K1,C:C,L1)
```

Assuming `Date` is in ColumnA.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(A2:A20,"mmm")="May"),--(B2:B20="C"),--(C2:C20="XX"))
```

Comment: The value of this answer would be greater if you could provide an explanation of how the mechanics of using SUMPRODUCT like this works; it would not be intuitive for those who have never seen this method before.